# React.js adding component to child

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
import FieldSect from "./fieldSect.js" 
<div>
  <FieldSect />
</div>
```

--FieldSect.js--

```
import Field from "./Field.js"
<div>
   <Field />
<button onclick={addField}> addField </field>
</div>
```

--Field.js--

```
function Field (){
    <div>
      <label> Test </label>
      <input type="text" />
    </div>
```

}

My code works in the part where Field is loaded immediately and is shown correctly. I am really struggling on trying to figure out how to keep adding the `<Field />` component under the already existing `<Field />` whenever the add button is clicked. I also need to ensure to have the ability to keep adding  rather than having a specific number of  available

I also cannot use the DOM as I am getting an error telling me to edit the state rather than using DOM.render

End Result should look something like this:
--FieldSect.js--

```
<div>
   <Field />
   ...<Field /> (Button Add Click)
   ...<Field /> (Button Add Click)
   ..
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should have `Fields` be part of the state of your parent component, perhaps as an array, `this.state = {fields:[{id:1},{id:2},{id:3}]}`.

Then, when rendering, you can iterate over the array:

```
<div>
   {this.state.fields.map(f => <Field key={f.id}/>)}
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Its super simple.

Have a default state of fields for example lets say that you want to have 1 field at the beginning

```
this.state = {
 fields: [<Field/>]
}
```

Now use `onClick` event for `AddClick` and a function as follows

```
handleOnClick=(event)=>this.setState(prevState=>({...prevState, fields: [...prevState.fields, <Field/>]})
```

And in your render function iterate over `fields array`

PS: I am not sure what is a Field doing.

What I would do is in render

```
<div>
   {this.state.fields.map(field => <Field {...field}/>)}
</div>
```

and fields would be the data of a field

Comment: Fields is literally just building all the elements I need that  is simply in a separate file

Comment: to clarify the button and you suggestion, the button should look <button handleOnClick=(event)=>this.setState(prevState=>({...prevState, fields: [...prevState.fields, <Field/>]})> Add Field </button>

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding you correctly, you're wanting to add a  every time someone clicks a button. If that's accurate, then I would simply add a constructor with a state to either the FieldSect.js or parent file to that (somewhere along the line before Field.js) that creates a trackable state.  Something like:

```
this.state = {
        NumberOfFields: 1
    };
```

If you do this ahead of FieldSect.js, then it needs to be passed down in props.

Now you need to set up the onClick function to increment this state. Using this, you can then create a loop in FieldSect.js that creates an array of elements that will be rendered in React.

```
let array = []
for(let i = 0; i < this.NumberOfFields; i++){
  array.push(<Field key={Math.random()}/>)
}
```

Then, instead of using  in FieldSect.js, use {array}.

The reason I added the key attribute to the Field is that all elements that are derived from an iteration like this must have a unique key.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go.

This holds the number of `<Fields />` in the state of a controlled component, which can be incremented with the button.

The loop is generated by creating an Array of `nbrOfFields` length, destructured, and then mapped over.

```js
const Field = () => (
  <div>
    <label> Test </label>
    <input type="text" />
  </div>
);

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {nbrOfFields: 1};
    this.addField = this.addField.bind(this);
  }
  
  addField() {
    this.setState(prevState => ({nbrOfFields: prevState.nbrOfFields + 1}));
  }
  
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {[...Array(this.state.nbrOfFields)].map((item, i) => (
          <Field key={i} />
        ))}
        <button onClick={this.addField}>Add field</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("app"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: I need this functionality without the use of DOM.render

Comment: @AlexBailey, I use `ReactDOM.render()` here because otherwise the snippet I made wouldn't work. In your react app, you would obviously only have one `ReactDOM.render()` which renders your top-level component to the DOM.